# Authy Desktop client - syncing token labels and icons across devices

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication

Is there a good solution for syncing Authy token labels and icons across devices? [Multi Device Sync](https://authy.com/features/multiple-devices/) has made Authy a vast improvement for me over gAuthenticator and dedicated security fobs. On iOS, Authy's tokens are labelled clearly by service. On the Linux Desktop client, many labels are generic and display only my username or email address associated with the account.

[Twillio Authy Desktop client - Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpyLm.png)

I use the same email for multiple services, so generic token labels are unhelpful. While I can explicitly assign token labels and icons, this has to be done from Authy's `Settings ... Accounts` screens for individual tokens. These screens do not display the current 2FA code -- so matching them to the correctly-labeled token on iOS difficult. Is there a recommended solution for syncing Authy token labels and icons across devices or a better way to manually update tokens?

Asking this question rubber ducked me into two manual workarounds:

I. Remove the '`:`' from default account names your Authy mobile app creates. Remove and re-add your Authy Desktop to Multi Device Sync. (Found [this solution on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacytoolsIO/comments/kbi1x7/on_authy_for_windows_desktop_my_accounts_are/gzlqqun/))

II. [This is a PITA] Match and update each Authy Desktop account to the related token on your mobile app. Open Authy Desktop Ubuntu (**ADU**) and have your Authy app on 2nd device in-hand (**2nd**).

From the `Settings ... Accounts` screen on **ADU**, for each token with the same email address and generic colored key logo, give each Account its own color.

From the `Tokens` screen on **ADU**, for each token with generic key logo, iterate through tokens on **2nd** device til I find the match. Note the **ADU** account color for the matching token on 2nd device.

From the `Settings ... Accounts` screen on **ADU**, update the `Account Name & Logo` from the matches you've created above.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I want to know how to correctly label tokens on Ubuntu Desktop client. The Authy account tokens are correctly labeled on iOS, but not Ubuntu. The [image of Authy Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpyLm.png) I included in my question demonstrates the issue, and I'm happy to clarify my question further apart from the image.

Comment: I've updated my q with manual workarounds. Authy has been aware of the [logo and label sync issue](https://support.authy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002908333-Adding-custom-logos-in-the-Authy-app) for years. It's an edge case or low prio for other reasons.  

> Do logos sync across devices?

> No. Changing the logo for an account token in the Authy app installed on one device will not change the logo for that same account token in the Authy app installed on a different device.

Comment: The inability to sync labels and logos across devices is more of a missing feature than a bug. Authy desktop app is where that missing feature became an issue for me. 
Should I update or re-tag my question to better abide by the guidelines?

Comment: I am sorry, it looks like your question has not received much attention (except from me). Maybe editing it will help. Best of luck.